# text overflow in left side if we set the textAlign as "right" for spark textinput control?

Tags: css, apache-flex, flash, skinning

if i use a textinput with

> textAlign="right"

when text is more than it can fit into, text is overflown, i want to hide text and not to over flow from right side.. and scroll the text using cursor(with left and right key) is possible if yes how ?

by using skin, i am able to clip the overflow.. but now cursor is not scrolling to left side.
[image]

any solution ?

Comment: Give us code for a runnable sample, not a screenshot of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to understand your problem I did the same that you did. So i added a textInput with a skinclass.

```
<s:TextInput id="io" skinClass="com.carsa.rumbo.cobros.ui.skin.io" text="123456789 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20"/>
```

and to see aall the properties of a textInput skin, you can choose textinput as hostcomponent class in the creation of skin.
I tried it this way and works as I think you wanted.

This is the skin code:

```
ADOBE SYSTEMS INCORPORATED
Copyright 2008 Adobe Systems Incorporated
All Rights Reserved.

NOTICE: Adobe permits you to use, modify, and distribute this file
in accordance with the terms of the license agreement accompanying it.
```

-->

```
 @see spark.components.TextInput

  @langversion 3.0
  @playerversion Flash 10
  @playerversion AIR 1.5
  @productversion Flex 4
```

-->

```
<fx:Metadata>
<![CDATA[ 
    /** 
     * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
     */
    [HostComponent("spark.components.TextInput")]
]]>
</fx:Metadata> 

<fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
    private var paddingChanged:Boolean;

    /* Define the skin elements that should not be colorized. */
    static private const exclusions:Array = ["background", "textDisplay"];

    /**
     * @private
     */   
    override public function get colorizeExclusions():Array {return exclusions;}

    /* Define the content fill items that should be colored by the "contentBackgroundColor" style. */
    static private const contentFill:Array = ["bgFill"];

    /**
     *  @private
     */
    override public function get contentItems():Array {return contentFill};

    /**
     *  @private
     */
    override protected function commitProperties():void
    {
        super.commitProperties();

        if (paddingChanged)
        {
            updatePadding();
            paddingChanged = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @private
     */
    override protected function initializationComplete():void
    {
        useChromeColor = true;
        super.initializationComplete();
    }

    /**
     *  @private
     */
    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        if (getStyle("borderVisible") == true)
        {
            border.visible = true;
            shadow.visible = true;
            background.left = background.top = background.right = background.bottom = 1;
            textDisplay.left = textDisplay.top = textDisplay.right = textDisplay.bottom = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            border.visible = false;
            shadow.visible = false;
            background.left = background.top = background.right = background.bottom = 0;
            textDisplay.left = textDisplay.top = textDisplay.right = textDisplay.bottom = 0;
        }

        borderStroke.color = getStyle("borderColor");
        borderStroke.alpha = getStyle("borderAlpha");

        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
    }

    /**
     *  @private
     */
    private function updatePadding():void
    {
        if (!textDisplay)
            return;

        // Push padding styles into the textDisplay
        var padding:Number;

        padding = getStyle("paddingLeft");
        if (textDisplay.getStyle("paddingLeft") != padding)
            textDisplay.setStyle("paddingLeft", padding);

        padding = getStyle("paddingTop");
        if (textDisplay.getStyle("paddingTop") != padding)
            textDisplay.setStyle("paddingTop", padding);

        padding = getStyle("paddingRight");
        if (textDisplay.getStyle("paddingRight") != padding)
            textDisplay.setStyle("paddingRight", padding);

        padding = getStyle("paddingBottom");
        if (textDisplay.getStyle("paddingBottom") != padding)
            textDisplay.setStyle("paddingBottom", padding);
    }

    /**
     *  @private
     */
    override public function styleChanged(styleProp:String):void
    {
        var allStyles:Boolean = !styleProp || styleProp == "styleName";

        super.styleChanged(styleProp);

        if (allStyles || styleProp.indexOf("padding") == 0)
        {
            paddingChanged = true;
            invalidateProperties();
        }
    }
</fx:Script>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
    /** 
     * @private 
     */     
    private static const focusExclusions:Array = ["textDisplay"];

    /**
     *  @private
     */
    override public function get focusSkinExclusions():Array { return focusExclusions;};
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal"/>
    <s:State name="disabled"/>
</s:states>

<!-- border --> 
<!--- @private -->
<s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" id="border">
    <s:stroke>     
        <!--- @private -->
        <s:SolidColorStroke id="borderStroke" weight="1" />
    </s:stroke>
</s:Rect>

<!-- fill -->
<!--- Defines the appearance of the TextInput component's background. -->
<s:Rect id="background" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1">
    <s:fill>
        <!--- @private Defines the background fill color. -->
        <s:SolidColor id="bgFill" color="0xFFFFFF" />
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>

<!-- shadow -->
<!--- @private -->
<s:Rect left="1" top="1" right="1" height="1" id="shadow">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="0x000000" alpha="0.12" />
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>

<!-- text -->
<!--- @copy spark.components.supportClasses.SkinnableTextBase#textDisplay -->
<s:RichEditableText id="textDisplay"
          verticalAlign="middle"
          widthInChars="10"
          left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" clipAndEnableScrolling="true"/>
```

Comment: this solved the problem.. but there is another issue is raised.. when i set alignment to right. the hidden text of left can't be scrolled through left arrow key.. on deleting the visible  text left text is  pushed to take place.. is there any solution ? :(